# Connecting a non-linear axis in matplotlib with spatial coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am hoping to graph data that looks something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 350, 40, 55, 60]
y = [0, 20, 40, 10, 20]
plt.scatter(x,y);
```

Gives something like this:

[image]

However I would like to change this so the axes run from 180 to 360 and then from 0 to 180 all in the same figure. Essentially I want connect 360 to 0 in the center of the figure.

Answer (score 1):

There might be something creative you can do with [`matplotlib.units`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/units_api.html), but I often find that interface to be quite clunky.

I'm not 100% certain the result you want, but from your description it sounds like you want a plot in cartesian coordinates with an `xaxis` that goes from 180 → 360 → 180. Unfortunately this is not directly doable with a single `Axes` in `matplotlib` (without playing around with the units above).

Thankfully, you can stitch together 2 plots to get the desired end result that you want:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 350, 40, 55, 60]
y = [0, 20, 40, 10, 20]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, grid
spec_kw={"wspace": 0})
ax1.scatter(x, y, clip_on=False)
ax2.scatter(x, y, clip_on=False)

ax1.set_xlim(180, 360)
ax1.set_xticks([180, 240, 300, 360])
ax1.spines["right"].set_visible(False)

ax2.set_xlim(0, 180)
ax2.set_xticks([60, 120, 180])
ax2.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax2.spines["left"].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The trick for the above is that I actually plotted all of the data twice (`.scatter(...)`), laid those plots out next to eachother (`{'wspace': 0}`) and then limited their data view (`.set_xlim`) to make it appear as a seamless plot that goes from 180 → 360 → 180.

---

You may also be asking for a plot not in cartesian coordinates, but in polar coordinates. In that case you can use the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import deg2rad

x = [0, 350, 40, 55, 60]
y = [0, 20, 40, 10, 20]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "pola
r"})
ax.scatter(deg2rad(x), y)
ax.set_yticks([0, 20, 40, 60])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most people would plot that as -180 to 180?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)

x = np.arange(0, 360, 10)
y = x * 1
y[x>180] = y[x>180] - 360

ax[0].scatter(x, np.abs(y), c=x)
ax[1].scatter(y, np.abs(y), c=x)
plt.show()
```

[image]